# A value of type const char* cannot be assigned to an entity of type char*?

Tags: c++

I have a class like the following (I've deleted extraneous items):

```
class GL_Texture
{
public:
    GL_Texture();

private:
    char* fileLocation;
};
```

It's constructor looks like this:

```
GL_Texture::GL_Texture()
{
    fileLocation = ""; //  error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
}
```

The constructor is producing an error  `error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'`. Even if I try to make `fileLocation` a `char* const`, I get the following error on that line

```
error C2166: l-value specifies const object
```

If I cannot assign a string literal to a char*, and I can't qualify `fileLocation` as pointer to const, how am I supposed to initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: `Even if I try to make fileLocation a char* const` It wants a `const char*`, not a `char* const`.

Comment: Use a `std::string`?

Comment: semi-ot: you are not supposed to initialize it *in* the constructor at all. Members are initialized before the constructor is executed: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: In C++ all literal strings are really arrays of `const` characters. They decay to `const char*` (or `char const*`). The type `char* const` is very different (it means the *pointer* is constant, not the data it points to).

Comment: `char* const` isn't pointer to const

Comment: Why not initialize the private member in place, like `char* fileLocation {};`

Comment: What is the difference between 
`const char *`
`char * const`
`char const *` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices:

1. First, the one most people will agree is the best in most situations: don't use `char *`, use `std::string`.
2. Second, initialize to [`nullptr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/nullptr?view=msvc-160) instead.
3. Third: `fileLocation = strdup("");` and then clean it up in the destructor. This is ugly.
4. Fourth: change it to `char const *`.